# Why are these two strings with linebreaks different?

Tags: c#, string, syntax, line-breaks

```
"[a='b\\\nc']"
```

And

```
@"[a='b\
c']"
```

Does the second add a `\r` or something? Is there an easy way to escape it so I can "see" the line break characters?

Comment: These two strings are exactly identical.

Comment: @Michael: No... they aren't. It *might* depend on your OS, but the second one contains a `\r`.

Comment: You're right - on Windows, the first contains a single linefeed, and the second a carriage-return and linefeed pair.

Comment: Was causing problems in my code and confusing the heck out of me. Now I know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Just tried putting it through `Regex.Escape` which escapes a bit more than it should, but it does show the `\r`.